# Questions with To Be v To Do

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I know **does it taste good** is grammatically correct. But is **is it good** correct?
Both are in reference to food.

I keep hearing people using the second, especially in American TV shows.

Comment: Yes, it's idiomatic **and** grammatically irreproachable!

Comment: What could be wrong with "Is it good".  Can you explain why you think it is wrong. It is very short and there is no complex grammar.  Do you think the meaning of "good" is wrong?